# Running wolframscript results in "Failed to open configuaration file at path"

Tags: scripting, configuration

The wolframscript configuration file exists and have all of the permission enabled. When I start wolframscript on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, it starts fine. However, it produces the following error message. I would really appreciate any help to get rid of this error message.

```
$ ls -la /home/someuser/.config/Wolfram/WolframScript/WolframScript.conf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 someuser someuser 136 Sep  6  2021 /home/someuser/.config/Wolfram/WolframScript/WolframScript.conf
$ wolframscript
Failed to open configuaration file at path: /home/someuser/.config/Wolfram/WolframScript/WolframScript.conf
Failed to open configuaration file at path: /home/someuser/.config/Wolfram/WolframScript/WolframScript.conf
Wolfram Language 12.2.0 Engine for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2020 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:=
```

Comment: From the shell, can you do a `cat` on the file? as `someuser` and as `root`. Show the first few lines of the file if you can.